# Seding emails with Devise gem and Mailgun Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailgun

I want to send automated emails via Mailgun either SMTP or API. The problem is that in tutorials I find they explain how to do that manually e.i creating mailer class etc. For example like that:

```html
def send_simple_message
  RestClient.post "https://api:YOUR_API_KEY"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
  :from => "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
  :to => "bar@example.com, YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
  :subject => "Hello",
  :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
end
```

This is from official Mailgun documentation.

But I am using Devise gem which has email sending implemented.

For example I want to send password reset email. When I click forgot password and submit my email from logs I see that my email is tried to be sent, but not sent of course, I need to set up email server.

So the question is where is this code for sending recovery email is written in devise, how to override it? I want it to oveeride so it will use Mailgun API for example.

I have already generated registrations_controller.rb using

> rails generate devise:controllers registrations

command. So I suppose I am overriding it here?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

have you read [this](https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password/) tutorial? Looks like you need to setup it in **config/environments/development.rb**

Something like:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
domain: ENV['GMAIL_DOMAIN'],
authentication: 'plain',
user_name: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
}
```

Also, you can try to use [mail gun gem](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails). Looks like It's really easy to setup it

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
        api_key: '<mailgun api key>',
        domain: '<mailgun domain>'
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: One crucial step after you do the above: make sure in **/config/initializers/devise.rb** you uncomment the line `config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'`. That will route devise's mailer through action mailer, which has now been configured to use Mailgun (or whatever).